# When are we first informed about Gerry Lane's profession?

Tags: character, world-war-z

In World War Z, Brad Pitt plays the role of a former UN investigator named Gerry Lane. When are we first informed of this fact?

When I watched the film, I spent half the movie wondering who he was that he could get a helicopter to specially ferry him and his family out of the city. It was only when he spoke to the naval honcho that I found out that he was a former UN man. Is this the first instance of this information being revealed to the audience?

I can remember a conversation about his job when the Lanes are having breakfast. But I don't recall the UN being mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the opening chatter does mention the UN and the WHO, and Gerry explains martial law to his daughter, we do not find out exactly what his profession is/was until he and his family are extracted and arrive on the warship (and, as in my question, speak to the naval man). This is also the first time that the UN is mentioned after the aforementioned opening chatter.

> The Under-Secretary here says you were his best investigator when you were at the U.N.

> You were on the ground during the Liberian Civil War. Investigated Chechen war crimes. Sri Lanka in '07. Places you and I both know Dr. Fassbach wouldn't last a night in.

This conversation occurs at around the 32 minute mark. Until then, we have no idea who he really is.

Answer (score 3):

No, the scene when his daughter mentions him doing pancakes all the time. I think he replied, *I've left my old job/or retired*. Also the daughter asked him what was Martial Law, which tells us that he was former military or in some Defence organization.